# VBA copy contents of a row and multiply it based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I have the following code

```
Sub copy()

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim copyCount As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")
    copyCount = .Value
    Set rngSource = .EntireRow.Range("C1:F1")
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    .Resize(copyCount, rngSource.Columns.Count).Value = rngSource.Value
End With

End Sub
```

What it does: It copies the contents of the first row from C1 to F1 on sheet2 and multiplies the number of rows based on the value that H2 has.  So if the cell H2 has the number 4, it takes all the cells from Sheet1 starting from C1 to F1 and makes 4 rows in Sheet2 with that.
Now I want it to do the same thing for each row that Sheet1 has as at the moment it only does the operation for 1 row.

I think the For Each loop would be required but I have tried several times and it failed me.

Any help is well received. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not so clear... Would you like to copy the range C:F of each existing rows (in Sheet1) and copy in Sheet2 so many time, each of them, as in "H2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. I hope I correctly understood your need. If not, please better describe it...

```
Sub copySpecial()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long, arrC As Variant
 Dim copyCount As Long, i As Long

 Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

 lastRow1 = sh1.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

 For i = 2 To lastRow1
   copyCount = sh1.Range("H" & i).Value
   arrC = sh1.Range("C" & i & ":F" & i)
   lastRow2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
   If lastRow2 < 14 Then lastRow2 = 14
   If copyCount > 0 Then
        sh2.Range("A" & lastRow2).Resize(copyCount, 4).Value = arrC
   End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes but to use the value of each row's 'H' cell. Like row1 may have H = 4 but row2 may have the H value to 2, and so on.

Comment: @steve88: I will adapt the code according to my last understanding... Adapted.

Comment: thank you for updating but now it says: Run time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: @steve88: If you do not say on which row the error appears, it is difficult to understand what happens. I only introduced the variable in the loop and updated it with `i` position... Did you change anything in the code? Even a minor change... In my case it does not return any error. Do you have two sheets named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2"?

Comment: @steve88:  Try refreshing the page (this one), please and copy the last code...

Comment: the error is on this line sh2.Range("A" & lastRow2).Resize(copyCount, 4).Value = arrC I did not change anything and I have Sheet1 and Sheet2, also it ran the first iteration as it copied the first row 4 times but then it stopped.

Comment: @steve88: What value has `lastRow2` on the error? Moving the cursor over the variable... Or `copyCount`, most probably ... Do you have values on whole H:H column? Do you have records in column A:A of Sheet1?

Comment: the value of lastRow2 is 18 and copyCount is 0. On the hole H:H columns there are different values, from 0 to 11. and there are records in the entire A:A column.

Comment: Resize 0 does not make sense! What do you want doing in case of 0? To avoid copying? If yes, you should say that... Adapted the code to skip the row copying in case of `copyCount = 0`.

Comment: @steve88: I must close my computer now. It is very late in my country... I hope the code does now what you need. If yes, we here tick the code left side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In such a case, somebody else searching for something similar, will know that the code works. If not, I will solve it tomorrow... Bye!